# Using iOS7 Background Fetch to ping the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, multitasking

I want to use iOS7's Background Fetch functionality in order to ping the server once a day.
I don't want to pull any new data - but I just want to know the app is still installed on the phone.

I can enable Background Fetch, set a Minimum Background Fetch Interval of 24 hours and always return `UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData` to the `completionHandler`.

I don't need it to be at an exact time each day. Once a day is more than enough.

Will Apple approve my app on the App Store?
Can I rely on the iOS to wake my app at least once a day and perform this action?
I'm afraid that if the answer will always be UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData iOS will stop waking my app.

Comment: Yes apple will aprove and ios will wake up ur app but u can't be sure that if will on that particular time interval(take in consideration +/- also) and alternative could be to use push notification to wake ur app and check if installed or not.

Comment: 1. I don't need it to be at an exact time each day. Once a day is more than enough.
2. I'm afraid that if the answer will always be UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData iOS will stop waking my app.

I added the two comments to the original question

Comment: Real issue will arrive when user will kill ur app so no backgroundfetch will work as no scope is present so no method will get called. So in that case puch notification is best option for u to use.

Comment: I was under the impression background fetch will work even if the app is not in the background (like I get Whatsapp and Facebook updates even when these apps are closed). Did I get it wrong? Only Remote Notifications will wake my app up?

Comment: Keep in mind that many people disable background activity due to battery drain.

Comment: Yep ....remote notification is for that purpose to wake ur app and perform some operation onto ur app. Also as said by @Till battery usage is a major concern too.

Comment: If the user manually disables background activity it's ok. I will just lose data for that user until he opens the app again.

My question is - will Remote Notifications/Background Fetch will work even if the user has killed the app manually (swipe up from the multitasking screen).

The more I read about the subject it looks like if the user manually kills the app NO background activity will happen until the app will be relaunched.

Comment: Yes ,through remote/push notification could u do perform operation onto ur app or even open app. Also in iOS 8 apple provided interactive notification u could give it a look too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Background Fetch and Remote Notifications **WILL NOT** work if your app was killed by the user.

According to the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:):

> However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user
>   has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app
>   or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app
>   automatically again.

Comment: removed my comment as it was now confusing :-)